# Data not refreshed after delete in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-hooks

After deleting a record, the player data still displays in Home screen and it is not refreshed. Only after navigating to some other screen I can see the updated data in Home screen.

I have tried put the `setSearchResults(searchResults)` state inside `onDelete()` but it doesn't work.

`Home.js`

Below is the get method to display player data in Home screen:

```
 const [playerList, setPlayerList] = useState([]);
    const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.get('http://localhost:8000/service/players');
        if (isMounted.current) {
        setPlayerList(res.data.players);
        setSearchResults(res.data.players);
        const privilege = localStorage.getItem('Privilege');
        console.log("What is getting in Front End:" + privilege);
        showDeleteIcon(privilege);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);


    const onDelete = id => () => {
        try {
          Axios.delete('http://localhost:8000/service/player', {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
          data: {
            'id' : id
          }
        });
          setDeleteDialog(false);
          //setSearchResults(searchResults);
          //setPlayerList(playerList);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
      }
```

`server.js`

```
app.delete('/service/player', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = req.body.id;
    console.log("Req"+userId);
    const deletePlayer = await UserModel.destroy({
      where:{ id : userId }
    })
    res.status(200).json({ deletePlayer });
    } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ fail: e.message });
   }
});
```

Comment: Is the 'record' part of the `searchResults` state?

Comment: If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects, so you need to setSearchResults with a new set of data that doesn't have the deleted record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the deleted record is actually part of the `searchResults` state that is defined as part of the `Home.js` component, you will need to update the state after the `Axios.delete` request is successful. This can be done by filtering(using `Array.filter`) the other results which do not match the `id`.

I am not sure the exact structure of `searchResults`, but I assume that `id`, which is the parameter passed into the `onDelete` method is one of the unique properties of each object within the `searchResults` array.

```
const onDelete = id => () => {
    try {
      Axios.delete('http://localhost:8000/service/player', {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
      data: {
        'id' : id
      }
    });
      setDeleteDialog(false);

      const remainingResults = searchResults.filter((result) => result.id !== id)
      setSearchResults(remainingResults);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: That got worked now, thank you. Upvoted the answer. Curios to know how come the page navigation displays the updated data ?

Comment: Hmm.. I am guessing that is because when you navigate back to this component, it will re-render with the updated data, because you are actually fetching the data on that useEffect() hook